# How to use enum values as keys in typescript interfaces?

Tags: typescript, interface

I am looking for a way to use enum's key to define an interface's allowed keys, how do you achieve this?

http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYOwrgtgBA4qAmwBOUDeAoKUIEMA2wUAvFAOS4GkA0mUAZsBYSaQ06egL7roCWIAF2R0cAY0IAFZAGcA9iDS0QOCMABcUaQKT8A5gG5auhMg1adIA1x6j5WqAAdgshwQ1SkckAG0AusShvWlQoZVUNUgBZHCQAT2ooYxBEJAi2fGBSKE4aLBCw9TIAKWQ4hKSUiPZs3LRQlULSItlMqkSTVLJq7l8efiEkEXEoKRcCGCRZMCd4ACFYuGTkRSwAelWoAAkAUQAlbY0AC1kAdygBWSgwaUIBQ8JQSHPLxGlRHQAjW-vAgGtgWL+ABu+DAhHuSGAAH5aN5-rENPDZHRzrEnMjYB1fO4ZPI-NZ0LYQPZ0a5gBMpjN5otKiNnGSKdNgHMFh0AhgsN4acgAHTpAjYxz0gi1JgaUkELhAA

```
enum Gender {
  male = 'male',
  female = 'female'
}

interface Person {
  name: string;
  gender: string;
}

const people: Person[] = [
  { name: 'Mary', gender: 'female' },
  { name: 'Jerry', gender: 'male' },
  { name: 'Joe', gender: 'male' }
]

interface PeopleGroupedByGender {
  // HERE: how to use the enum to describe the [key] value here?
  [key: keyof typeof Gender]: Person[]
}

const peopleGroupedByGender: PeopleGroupedByGender = {
  [Gender.female]: people,
  male: people
}
```

Comment: Please next time past the code in your post (with the link), thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error message:

> An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.

As the message indicates, you can solve this by using a [mapped object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
type PeopleGroupedByGender = {
  [key in keyof typeof Gender]: Person[]
}
```

Comment: Because typescript does not support that. The [reason given](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5683#issuecomment-289156971) is that "Mapped types are only supported in type aliases. Interfaces and classes have merging semantics that do would not fit make much sense with mapped type."

Comment: this is limiting the key to the enum key, not to the value of the enum key.  is there a way to do that? let's say i have enum enum SomeOptions {
    Option1 = "Abc",
    Option2 = "Xyz"
}, i want to limit the key to lower case abc and xyz, is there a quick way to do that?